# google_maps_key was entered but still blank/didn't work

Tags: android, dictionary

i use demo sample script for build google map client on android,

in ..ApiDemos\app\src\release\res\values\google_maps_api.xml

```
<string name="google_maps_key" translatable="false" templateMergeStrategy="preserve">
        AIzaSyA76USspcg333E7Wh11RIkNRuuXXXXXXX
</string>
```

i was entered make api key like in documentations procedur step by step, but is't still not working

..\ApiDemos\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapdemo">
```

i use the package like on Manifest
and use the package as SHA-1 signing-fingerprint

its not just for this build app..

in other myproject also dint work

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyA76USspcg333E7Wh11RIkNRuuQQPSQy6Y"/>
```